# PHP fulltext search not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, full-text-search

I'm trying to perform a FULLTEXT search on a column, and further FULLTEXT search in Boolean mode if the first returns zero rows. If I enter the SQL queries into MySQL manually at the command line I get the result I expect, but this code is returning an empty array to my JS.
Any ideas where I'm going?

```
$con = mysqli_connect( $db_url, $db_user, $db_pwd, $db );
if( !$con ) {
error_log("Connection failed!");
die();
}

$sql = "SELECT problem, note_text, doctor, entry_date FROM notes WHERE mrn=? AND MATCH(note_text) AGAINST(?)";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare( $con, $sql );
mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt, 'is', $_POST['mrn'], $_POST['search_text'] );
$success = mysqli_stmt_execute( $stmt );

if( mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 0 ) { // Then try fulltext search in boolean mode

    $sql = "SELECT problem, note_text, doctor, entry_date FROM notes WHERE mrn=? AND MATCH(note_text) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare( $con, $sql );
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt, 'is', $_POST['mrn'], $_POST['search_text'] );
    $success = mysqli_stmt_execute( $stmt );
} 

    mysqli_bind_result( $stmt, $problem, $note_text, $doctor, $date );
    $notes = array();

    for( $i = 0; mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt) == TRUE; ++$i ) {
        $notes[$i] = array( 'problem' => $problem, 'note' => $note_text, 'doctor' => $doctor, 'date' => $date );
    }

    $json = json_encode($notes);
    echo $json;
```

Comment: all of your code is simply assuming the query calls succeeded. never assume success. assume failure and treat success as a pleasant surprise.  start checking return values from your mysqli calls.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll add in a check. But assuming it succeeds (it's all localhost for now) ...

Comment: there's exactly ONE way for a query to suceeds: it just works. But a near infinite number of ways to fail. only **ONE** of those ways if the db server crashing or whatever. there's still sql syntax errors, which are an all-too-common occurence on this site. You need to handle all of those cases.

Comment: The SQL, as I said in the post, definitely works. I've run it in MySQL itself, so the problem doesn't lie in the SQL queries

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think I have found the answer. I needed to close the first STATEMENT $stmt before I used the second one with a call to

```
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt)
```

just after

```
if( mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 0 )
```

Simply doing

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare( $con, $sql );
```

doesn't get you a new statement and overwrite the previous variable!